# Mouseout and mouseleave not working

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using `mouseout` and `mouseleave` methods but both are not working. I tried to fix it but cant find the solution. My code looks fine, it has no errors so I want to know why it is not working. Here is example code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Dpp8a/)

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen()
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('.mydiv').addClass('redbrd')
    })

    $('.redbrd').live('mouseover', function(){
        var htm= '<div id="mmt">some text</div>'
        $('body').append(htm)
    })
    $('.redbrd').live('mouseout', function(){
        $('#mmt').remove()
    })
})
```

Comment: You creating multiple div-s with the same id. Maybe class is what you are looking for not id.

Comment: Also, it's bad practice not to use semicolons after each line.

Comment: In your original post, you try to register the events on elements with  a class that none of the elements in the html have yet when the page loads.

Comment: yes, I want to add class with click function then add mouseenter and mouseleave event on that class

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your fiddle page, there might be some issues with the mouse events being detected due to the complication of the code aside from this part, however using this should get you most of the way there:

```
$(function() {
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();

    $('a').click(function() {
        $('.mydiv').removeClass().addClass('redbrd mydiv');// NOTE this is in case your other question comes into play with this one.
    });
    $('body').on('mouseenter', '.redbrd', function() {
       $('body').append('<div class="mmt">some text</div>');
    });
    $('body').on('mouseleave', '.redbrd', function() {
        $('.mmt').remove();
    });
});
```

EDIT:  After review, your adding li to the page after your chosen thing.

This should work with that:

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen();
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('.mydiv').addClass('redbrd');

        $('.redbrd').on('mouseover', 'li', function(e) {
            var $target = $(e.target);
            if ($('#mmt').length === 0) {
                var htm = '<div id="mmt">' + $target.text() + ' some text</div>';
                $('body').append(htm);
            }
        });
        $('.redbrd').on('mouseout', function() {
            $('#mmt').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Updated your fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/JtQHY/1/ so you can test it.

Comment: it is not working, is there any other method show popup rather than mouseenter and nouseout

Comment: I think we need more details here then: exact version of browser, what exactly are you seeing that is ineffective/not as desired.  And, perhaps a more limited example (if possible) functionally.

Comment: remove padding from .mydiv, then hover select type. it should append #mmt on body and mouseout it then it should remove #mmt. Thats it

Comment: I find the solution for this, actually chosen jquery plugin using mouseenter and mouseleave method. It is blocking out mouseenter and mouseout function. I put my function into chosen plugin and it works

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the events are not being caught because they are not exactly bubbling properly.

Live depends on proper bubbling of events. I think the chosen plugin breaks the bubbling

Try this:

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen()
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('.mydiv').addClass('redbrd')

        $('.redbrd').live('mouseover',function(){
            if($('#mmt').length == 0){
                var htm= '<div id="mmt">some text</div>';
                $('body').append(htm);        
            }    

        }); 
        $('.redbrd').live('mouseout',function(){
            $('#mmt').remove();
        });          


    })        
})
```

With added css:

```
.mydiv{padding:10px;}
```

This makes the div that you are mousing over large enough that you are not instantly entering and exiting it. To see this working in your current example, slowly approach the bottom right corner of the red border until you 'enter' the div in the minuscule white space that is between the select and the div. then move out. You will see it works as expected.

[I added the changes I mentioned to a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JtQHY/) You can see it working there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using live to bind events to functions, I used the jQuery methods for `mouseover` and `mouseout`. In this example, I set up a `span` within the containing `div` that shows when your mouse enters the `div` and hides when you leave the `div`.

You could change the `span` to any element you would like to use, and style/position it with CSS if you like.

Is this a viable solution for your problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/Dpp8a/4/

Comment: He uses live. So there is no problem here.

Comment: @dystroy no elements have the class he tries to bind the events to on page load. he adds the class thru the click of the link.

Comment: @ZackT. That is not a big issue but if you think i have remove click event and calling event with existing class please check updated code http://jsfiddle.net/Dpp8a/2/

Comment: Is the point of what you are trying to do, to show a message to the user when they hover over your select box?

Comment: yes i want to show massage when user hover custom select menu and when he mouseout the custom select menu it should hide

Comment: when mouseout the select menu not hiding the massage

Comment: @jchand [Take a look at this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448468/why-cant-i-reliably-capture-a-mouseout-event) It has some discussion on why the mouseout event can't always reliably be caught.