# How can I trigger only one line

Tags: css, list, reactjs, hover, material-ui

I have a component How its work; When I mouse over on list object so its working anyway

```js
import React from 'react';

const ExampleComponent = ({show}) => {
  const componentClasses = ['example-component'];
  if (show) { componentClasses.push('show'); }

  return (
    <div className={componentClasses.join(' ')}></div>
  );
};

ExampleComponent.propTypes = {
  show: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default ExampleComponent;
```

And I'm using like this;

```
 import SubButtons from './subButtons';

 return shownAccountList.map((item) => {
  return(
    <List>
      <ListItem
        primaryText={text={ item.accountItem }}
      />
      <SubButtons show={this.state.subButtonsVisible}/>
    </List>
  );
```

This result: [image]

Expected Result; I want only trigger the element I brought to the mouse
for example if I selected line 1 Should work under the only line 1

Btw: I'm using `material-ui` . I accept if you have another recommendation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. If you can provide more details or a working demo that would really help. Based on what I think you mean, maybe take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41145452/8378419

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking with this question.

Comment: `const ExampleComponent = ({show}) => {` should probably be `const ExampleComponent = props => {`, and `if (show)` should be `if (this.props.show)`

Comment: Actually thats clear with image. So I want only this; its rendering when I over on a line its back to a component. So I sent it a boolean value and its back to a component. But this rendering every line I want only selected line. Just imagine look the pic. and close second red one for example My cursor on the firts line and there is a only one red line You got it ?