# How can i use hover in attribute using javascript object?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
const customPanelStyle = {
   'background-color': 'red', 
   'border': '1px solid green',
    ':hover'{
        'background': 'blue'    
    }
}
class some extends React.Component{
render(){
return(
   <Panel header={value} key="1" style={customPanelStyle} >
     <p>{this.state.content[key]}</p>
   </Panel>
)
}

}
```

How can use o attribute `hover` in this case? My exemple doesn't work.. what i have to do?

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52017547/4062197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Radium library

```
import Radium from 'radium';
 some = Radium(some);
    const customPanelStyle = {
       'background-color': 'red', 
       'border': '1px solid green',
        ':hover':{
            'background': 'blue'    
        }
    }
```

more info about [radium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/radium)

Comment: it doesn't work too... 
gets red in '{', saying it expects a ':', but even putting ':' does not work... <Panel is an object from `ant.design`... `import { Collapse} from 'antd'` and `const Panel = Collapse.Panel`

Comment: updated my answer