# Change cursor on Hover in react-konva

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-konva, konva

I'm using react-konva to create a UI for an application. I want it so that the cursor changes to a pointer when hovering over a Rect. There is documentation for how to do it with konva but not for react-konva. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It works very similarly to Konva demos.

```js
<Rect
  width={50}
  height={50}
  fill="red"
  onMouseEnter={e => {
    // style stage container:
    const container = e.target.getStage().container();
    container.style.cursor = "pointer";
  }}
  onMouseLeave={e => {
    const container = e.target.getStage().container();
    container.style.cursor = "default";
  }}
/>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-cursor-style-demo-96in7

Answer (score 0):

Have you  tried to use synthetic event **onMouseOver** and many other events.

Check this thread, 
[How do you Hover in ReactJS? - onMouseLeave not registered during fast hover over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981236/how-do-you-hover-in-reactjs-onmouseleave-not-registered-during-fast-hover-ove)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could merge two events:

```
const handleCursor = (e: KonvaEventObject<MouseEvent>) => {
   const stage = e.target.getStage();
   if (stage) {
     if (e.type === "mouseenter") {
       stage.container().style.cursor = "pointer";
     } else {
       stage.container().style.cursor = "default";
     }
   }
};
```