# Change state as long as mouse is over an element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a counter functional component, with 2 buttons: `increment` and `decrement` and currently, when they're **clicked**, the state changes. But I want the state to change **as long as the mouse is over the element**. (not like `onMouseOver` that executes the event if the mouse is over, and then again when you move the mouse out from the element and then hover on the element again). I want it to be a constant hover event.

Heres my `counter` code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter - 1)} disabled={counter < 1 ? true : false}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I hope that makes sense! Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-onhover-event-handling-with-examples

Comment: Probably I would try with `onMouseDown`, `onMouseEnter`, `onMouseLeave` events based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981236/how-do-you-hover-in-reactjs-onmouseleave-not-registered-during-fast-hover-ove). One addition is I would include a debounce into the event in order not to trigger several times in a second, refer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/perform-debounce-in-react-js).

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go :

For that, you might need one state variable that start and stops the interval on mouse hover and out,

Run the below code snippet, hope that will clear your doubts.

```js
const { useState , useEffect , useRef } = React;

const App = () => {

  const _intervalRef = useRef(null);
  const [startCounter,setStartCounter] = useState(false);
  const [counter,setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(startCounter) {
         _intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
          setCounter((counter) => counter+1);
      },250);
    } else {
      clearInterval(_intervalRef.current);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(_intervalRef.current);
  },[startCounter]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div onMouseOver={() => setStartCounter(true)} onMouseOut={() =>setStartCounter(false)}>
        HOVER ME TO START COUNTER : { counter }
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Roy, Glad it helped, :)